# Is it possible to use IB to automatically change the size of items upon rotation?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a view in IB which contains an image. When viewed in portrait mode the image is fairly large and if the device flips to portrait the image need shrinking to fit the narrower screen height.

Is it possible in IB to specify two sizes for image, one for landscape and one for portrait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IB to automatically adjust image views to be relative to its surrounding views which if you can make work is a good solution but if you need exact pixel sizes you will probably need to do that in code.